# How to integrate Firebase Crashlytics for iOS part of Flutter app?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I am trying to integrate `firebase_crashlytics` in my Flutter App.
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_crashlytics#-readme-tab-
I am facing an issue with iOS integration. In the docs, it is specified that `If on Xcode 10 Add your app's built Info.plist location to the Build Phase's Input Files field. Eg: $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)`

I have already created the Firebase project and did the initial setup required on the iOS part like pod install for Firebase and adding code in AppDelegate File.

I am not able to figure out what does this means? does it mean the literal path of `info.plist` file. I downloaded the sample project mentioned in the docs but it does not have anything related to the above point. I did something as below
[image]

I literally added the path to my `info.plist` file as below `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(/Users/priitshsawant/Desktop/firebase_crashltics/firebase_crashltics/ios/Runner/Info.plist)`. I tried crashing my app but it is not showing up in Firebase Crashlytics

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be perfectly fine by just leaving it as `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)`
This will resolve to your absolute path of the `Info.plist` once Xcode is building.

Just like so:

[image]

Comment: I am not able to see my crash in Crashlytics. Is it because of simulator??

Comment: What kind of crash did you produce? Did you clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem following these steps.

1. Make sure that **Run Script** is added as mention by the `Robin Reiter`
2. Run `Flutter Clean`
3. Run `Pod install`
4. Then use `Xcode to build and run`
5. if it's not working with the actual device use the simulator

Answer (score 0):

it's work for me in firebase_crashlytics: 2.5.1:

> ${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run

not use

> "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"

[image]